# upgrade TLS v1.1 to TLS V 1.2 on qt 4.7

Tags: qt, openssl, tls1.2, qt4.7, tls1.1

use  Tls v 1.1 in qt 4.7 lib and patch in my program, but need to upgrade the networkMangement to TLS V1.2 but not working  how i resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you tell use what is not working now?

Comment: thanks for u , i used tls 1.1 with qt 4.8